# XGBoost hyperparameter tuning: PR-AUC changed after optimization and not stable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, hyperparameters, precision-recall

Update:
I increate the CV to 5 and still the same problems exist.

### Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

I would like to perform the hyperparameter tuning of XGBoost. Due to the class imbalance, I used PR-AUC (average_precision) as score for evaluating the model performance. Also I performed optimization on one/two parameter each time (RandomizedSearchCV) to reduce the parameter combination number.

Steps I take:

The 1st piece of code below optimize subsample and the results show best subsample is 0.8.

Then I used subsample=0.8 and optimize colsample_bytree and max_depth. However, the final performance is slightly lower than 1st model. 
(Notes: although I used randomizedsearchCV, I do search all the parameter space by adjusting param_comb.)

I would expect the optimization in 2nd model will increase the PR-AUC. (The hyperparameter of the best model from 1st optimization is actually contained in the hyperparameter space of 2nd optimization.)
I have been thinking out the following possibilities:

1) cross-validation = 3 may not be big enought? this may cause results variation

2) random_state is not setup properly?

```
# import libraries
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
```

```
1st optimization: 
params = {
        'min_child_weight': [1],
        'gamma': [0],
        'subsample': [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
        'colsample_bytree': [0.8],
        'max_depth': [5],
        'n_estimators': [600]
        }
model1 = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1, objective='binary:logistic', scale_pos_weight=1, seed=27,
                    silent=True, nthread=4)

param_comb = 7
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle=True, random_state=1001)
# X,Y Both refer to training datasets.
model1_rs = RandomizedSearchCV(model1, param_distributions=params, n_iter=param_comb, scoring='average_precision', n_jobs=-1, cv=skf.split(X,Y), verbose=3, random_state=1001)
model1_rs.fit(X, Y)
print(average_precision_score(y_test, model1_rs.best_estimator_.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1], average="micro"))
# 0.7302823843908489
print(average_precision_score(y_train, model1_rs.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1], average="micro"))
# 0.7827743151047564
```

```
# 2nd optimization
params = {
        'min_child_weight': [1],
        'gamma': [0],
        'subsample': [0.8], # model 1 suggest 0.8 is the best as shown model1_rs.best_params_
        'colsample_bytree': [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
        'max_depth': [3, 4, 5, 6],
        'n_estimators': [600]
        }
model2= XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1, objective='binary:logistic', scale_pos_weight=1, seed=27,
                    silent=True, nthread=4)

param_comb = 32 # there are 8*4 combination in the paramater space.
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle=True, random_state=1001)

model2_rs = RandomizedSearchCV(model2, param_distributions=params, n_iter=param_comb, scoring='average_precision', n_jobs=-1, cv=skf.split(X,Y), verbose=3, random_state=1001)

model2_rs.fit(X, Y)

print(average_precision_score(y_test, model2_rs.best_estimator_.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1], average="micro"))
# 0.7302083383917825
print(average_precision_score(y_train, model2_rs.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1], average="micro"))
# 0.7741629881312448
```

Comment: Any idea is appreciated:)